# Importing 9000 eml files to Thunderbird .78

Tags: email, thunderbird, import, import-mail

Folder containing 9069 .eml files sent by Windows Live Mail.

I need to add them to Thunderbird. I created sub-folder in Thunderbird Archieved items, selected all files in Windows Explorer and dragged files them to this folder into this folder.

Thunderbird shows icon with number of files and freezes about 30 seconds.
After that nothing happes.
I tried several times from and to different folders but problem presists.
Importing small number of .emf files works.

How to import 9000 eml files to Thunderbird ?

Using 32 bit Thunderbird 78.1.0 in 64-bit latest Windows 10

ImportExportTools plugin has notice that it works only with Thunderbird 14.0 - 60.

I asked it also in Thunderrbird support at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1298295
but havent got answer.

[image]

** Update **

Thunderbird does not allow to install ImportExportTools NG

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [ImportExportTools NG add-on](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/)
is the evolution of this tool which is compatible with Thunderbird 68.

Try importing all the files using ImportExportTools NG.
If it also chokes up on so many files, you will need to import them in smaller
bunches.

Comment: Thunderbird does not allow to install it. I updated question and added image. Install option is not active

Comment: I didn't have any problem installing it like this: (1) Download the `xpi` file, (2) Start Thunderbird and enter menu *Tools > Add-ons*. (3) Drag & drop the `xpi` file into the page, (4) Accept the prompt to install, (5) Restart Thunderbird.

Comment: After dropping I received error message that addon cannot installed since it is not compatible with this version of Thunderbird.

Comment: The [Thunderbird blog](https://blog.thunderbird.net/2020/07/whats-new-in-thunderbird-78/) recommends not updating to Thunderbird 78 yet, since there may be problems with add-ons. I suggest going back to the release Thunderbird 68 where everything works. Once you have imported the emails, you may upgrade Thunderbird to 78 again (but beware add-ons).

Comment: I haver used Thunderbird 78 for a while and have lot of emails in it. Is it possible to downgrade so that emails from 78 will converted to older version also..

Comment: Just take a backup of the profile folder just in case.

Comment: I have found that dragging eml files copies random 400 emails from 9000 emails. Sometimes script timeout warning appears. I select wait but no more emails are copied.  Dragging single eml file works but original file still remains. This makes difficult to understand which files are not copied. Maybe I should split 9000 eml files to separate directories and drag them manually. How distribute 9000 files to separate directories in windowsm maybe 100 files per directory.

Comment: From your experience, you might be able to go higher, not bypassing 400.

Comment: It looks like This is programmed in javascript in Thunderbird. Maybe it is possible to increase script timeout to fix this ? How ?

Comment: Have you tried Thunderbird 68 with ImportExportTools NG? It's not supposed to have any limits on the import size. As far as compatibility goes, I think the Thunderbird database format is pretty standard across versions. It's easy enough to test, and with backups you take no risk.

Comment: I havent installed 68. 78 looks nicer, want to keep it.

Comment: You could return to version 78 after the import. You could also then uninstall ImportExportTools NG.